# The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized. (Serverside Redirect)

Tags: .net

Hi I'm trying to get the html code of the url ("http://dx.doi.org/10.1038/nclimate1398"), the following error occurs. I've tried many ways mentioned in this site but it's not working. This is my code.

> **It's working in Web Browser without providing Username and Password**.

```
dim url as string = "http://dx.doi.org/10.1038/nclimate1398"
Dim myRequest = CType(WebRequest.Create(url), HttpWebRequest)
myRequest.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials
myRequest.PreAuthenticate = True
myRequest.AllowAutoRedirect = True
Dim response = myRequest.GetResponse()
Dim responseStream = response.GetResponseStream()
Dim responseReader = New StreamReader(responseStream)
Dim result = responseReader.ReadToEnd()
Return result
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: Sounds like you need the correct username and password.

Comment: Hello Peter Ritchie, Without username and password the link is working properly in web browser

Comment: Have you tried setting the useragent to the same as your browser?